# no me carga mi javascript al iniciar la vista en mvc , carga al cambiar las opciones y necesito que crage al comenzar

Tags: javascript

```
FPromocion: function () {
    var $FPromocion = $("select[id = FactoresRiesgo_CanRemision]");
    var $FPromocionCual = $("select[name=FactoresRiesgoRemision]");
    var $FFecha = $("input[id=FactoresRiesgo_FechaRemision]");
    //$FPromocionCual.prop("disabled", true);

    $FPromocion.change(function () {
        var $that = $(this),
            FPromocion = $that.val();

        $FPromocionCual.prop("disabled", FPromocion != "0");
        $FFecha.prop("disabled", FPromocion != "0");

    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la función `trigger` de jquery.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$FPromocion.change(function () {
    var $that = $(this),
        FPromocion = $that.val();

    $FPromocionCual.prop("disabled", FPromocion != "0");
    $FFecha.prop("disabled", FPromocion != "0");

}).trigger("change");
```

Si necesitas ejecutarlo en otra lugar (que no se cuándo se declara el evento), solo debes de hacer referencia al elemento (en tu caso es `$("select[id = FactoresRiesgo_CanRemision]")`) y llamar la función trigger.

Por ejemplo:

```
$("select[id = FactoresRiesgo_CanRemision]").trigger("change");
```

O puede utilizar `$FPromocion` ya que este hace referencia al elemento:

```
$FPromocion.trigger("change");
```

> [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/): Ejecuta todos los controladores y comportamientos
>   adjuntos a los elementos coincidentes para el tipo de evento dado.